# asp codes wont be executed on server

Tags: asp.net, server

I'm pretty new with *ASP* , but Im looking for an answer to this question and nothing found yet.

Im using an Apache server to upload my website on it. i write a very simple asp code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%
response.write("My first ASP script!")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

and save the file as file.asp & get this as result:

[image]

Is the problem Apache server or what? What Should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your server to process ASP pages.
Start with this [Running ASP.Net on a Linux based server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116175/running-asp-net-on-a-linux-based-server)

If you are using old legacy ASP (not ASP.NET) then you may have trouble this platform is not actively developed from more than 10 years now. It would be better to switch to more modern framework e.g. ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `IIS` web server rather. Moreover is it asp.net or classic asp? By any means if it results in `<%response.write("My first ASP script!")%>` that means web server somehow processing it a normal HTML and not understand the script block `<% %>` which can only happen if it's processed by ASP.NET dll or ASP dll.