# Develop and deploy ASP.NET Core app on Tomcat Apache

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 questions on ASP.NET Core:

1) What code should be written in ASP.NET Core Startup file and configuration to run on Apache Tomcat Server.

2) How do I deploy my ASP.NET Core app on Apache Tomcat server.

Appreciate your time on this and thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Asp.net Core doesn't have support for Tomcat at the moment or if there is its changing to rapidly to get a stable setup. Using  Mono might be a possible solution. Not sure as I can't seem to get it to work.

- [Net core running asp-net app through apache tomcat](http://forums.dotnetfoundation.org/t/net-core-running-asp-net-app-through-apache-tomcat-etc/1129/5)
- [Running ASP.Net on a Linux based server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116175/running-asp-net-on-a-linux-based-server)

Comment: ...Thanks for your response. We are developing a non core ASP.NET web app because of our requirement constraints. MongoDB, RabbitMQ, Redis Cache dont have .NET Core connectors.

Comment: @AnilJain I see, probably a better choice at the moment but as I understand Asp.net Core does has the capabilities.