# How to deploy service based web apps on apache in linux?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, linux, apache, webmin

So i have a Linux based Server having webmin

And i made an web application having some css/js and a html and i put that folder in var/www/html/TestAPI

installed Apache Web server and every other module recommended

My question is ,how do i make this run as a service,like when i ping the HTML inside this folder it opens up but doesnt load any js/css

How do i execute this when i just open TestAPI
eg:- http://11.11.11.11/TestAPI
(Tried using index.html)
I dont want to use php

Any Help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: If you're planning to use apache and linux, you can forget about asp.net-mvc.

You should take a look at PHP, especially at routing. You can also look at the HTTP HEAD request.

Comment: so its not possible to deploy asp.net mvc on linux ??

Comment: It is, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116175/running-asp-net-on-a-linux-based-server#23996233), but for a service-based API system, I'd rather recommend PHP or, if you're expecting some load, JavaEE.
Asp.NET is quite heavy for the task

Comment: Unfortunately i have an requirement from my client right now and they are against PHP :/ so ASP is not compatible at all or am i missing something ??

Comment: I am just saying that you'll have a hard time using ASP for that task, and you'd rather go with a JavaEE architecture if PHP is unavailable.

Comment: @Artemis thanks a lot for your help mate..i think i'll have to stick with PHP,its been 10 days and i've had no success deploying .net on linux