# Is it possible to host Asp.net MVC Website in Linux

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a website made with Asp.net MVC with framework 4.5 developed in Visual studio 2015, . Is it possible to host it with linux. Language used c#

Comment: I think no. The old MVC is for IIS. The new Asp.Net Core can be hosted on linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running ASP.Net on a Linux based server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116175/running-asp-net-on-a-linux-based-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host .net core on Linux. But for .net 4.5, it is working on Windows platform. I personally never try to host .net core on Linux, I always use Windows here.